# Page transitions with forge native TopBar

Tags: trigger.io, forge

Does anyone know if it is possible to have the native TopBar element from the forge API animate in/out with the rest of the page when creating transitions? I want to have various screens slide in and out but the TopBar remains fixed even when animating the html or body tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point [Trigger's official API docs](http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/modules/topbar.html) only provide the option to plainly add and remove buttons.

Given the fact that the native topbar is outside of the webview you are working in, there is no way to change its behavior besides using their API. A possible workaround would be to build the topbar on your own within the webview using HTML and CSS (which can lead to other issues like fixed headers).